# Why is my simple Array only printing zeros in java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class arrayTest
{
    public static void main(String  [] args){

        int[] arr=new int[11];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++){

            System.out.print ( arr[i] + "," ); //

        }

    }
}
```

The output I receive is `"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"`, I want it to print `1` through `10`.

Comment: you haven't initialized the values in it

Comment: Look at declaring an array literal. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/

Comment: Default value of the ints in an array which is not initialized is '0'. Since you haven't done the initializing of values inside the arrays, you'd be seeing 0 11 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't initialized the values in it. Try this

```
public class arrayTest
{
    public static void main(String  [] args){

        int[] arr=new int[11];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
          arr[i] = i;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++){

            System.out.print ( arr[i] + "," ); //

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you the problem was that it was missing arr[i]=1

Comment: @onlineuser please click the green check mark next to the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

An int array is initialized with all 0s. You need to first assign values to each element in the array. A simple way to do this is

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
     arr[i] = i; 
}
```