# Calculate absolute minimum difference between any two numbers of a huge integer array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a very long array in a Java program (300 000+ unsorted integers) and need to calculate the minimum absolute difference between any two numbers inside the array, and display the absolute difference and the corresponding pair of numbers as an output. The whole calculation should happen very quickly.

I have the following code, which would usually work:

```
private static void calcMinAbsDiff(int[] inputArray)
{
    Arrays.sort(inputArray);

    int minimum = Math.abs(inputArray[1] - inputArray[0]);

    int firstElement = inputArray[0];

    int secondElement = inputArray[1];

    for (int i = 2; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(Math.abs(inputArray[i] - inputArray[i-1]) < minimum)
        {
            minimum = Math.abs(inputArray[i] - inputArray[i-1]);

            firstElement = inputArray[i-1];

            secondElement = inputArray[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Minimum Absolute Difference : "+minimum);

    System.out.println("Pair of Elements : ("+firstElement+", "+secondElement+")");
}
```

However, the output I receive is all 0s. I believe this is because the array is way too long.

Comment: If your array has two 0’s next to each other, then the output will be all 0’s

Comment: For example, [1, 2, 0, 0, 3] - The minimum difference is 0, between the third and fourth numbers. Both elements are 0, which is correct. So, outputting all zeroes is also correct here.

Comment: The two 0s don't need to be next to each other initially.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. That was indeed the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two or more zeros and no negative integers in your dataset, then your output is expected. After sorting, then inputArray[0] and inputArray[1] would both be 0, and the difference would be 0. No other pair of adjacent elements would have an absolute difference less than 0, so minimum, firstElement, and second Element would all be 0 at the end of the algorithm.

If you really have no zeros in your dataset, or if you do have negative integers, then you may have an initialization problem. Check this thread:
[Why is my simple Array only printing zeros in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497038/why-is-my-simple-array-only-printing-zeros-in-java)

If that's not it, then only other thing I can think of is that you have a problem in the previous scope causing the data to get zeroed out.

I would try printing samples of your dataset at various points to see exactly where/when it's getting zeroed.

If you still have trouble, then post more info on the dataset and the scope which calls this function to help us see what's going on. Let us know how you make out!

Comment: I indeed had an issue with the list which caused it to have two 0s, thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you worked it out, and thanks for sharing what you found the problem to be.