# How to put an array(s) into another array - Java

Tags: arrays, output, store

I am trying to put an array(s) into another array so that I can output the numbers: 2, 7, 32, 8, 2. Must I be initializing the values somehow? Little confused. I tried three four loops but different results. There is a link somewhat similar: [Why is my simple Array only printing zeros in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497038/why-is-my-simple-array-only-printing-zeros-in-java)
My code is below.  Thank you in advanced.

```
 public class test
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
 

   int[] a = {2, 7, 32, 8, 2}; 
   int[] b = new int[a.length];  
   int[] c = new int[b.length];  
   int[][] d = {b}; 


     for(int z = 0; z < b.length; z++){
       System.out.print(b[z] + " ");
     } 

 System.out.println();

     for(int y = 0; y < c.length; y++){
       System.out.print(c.length + " ");
     }

 System.out.println();

     for(int x = 0; x < d.length; x++){
       System.out.print(d.length + " ");
     }


   }
 }
 
 ------------------------
 OUTPUT
 0 0 0 0 0
 5 5 5 5 5
 1
```

///////////////////////////

```
 //NEW CODE
 import java.util.*;

 public class Main {

   public static void main (String[]args) {

        int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] arr2 = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        int[] arr3 = {10, 11, 12};
        int[] arr4 = {13, 14, 15, 16, 17};
        int[][] arrOfarrs = {arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4};
        int a[] = new int[arrOfarrs.length];

        for (int z = 0; z < arrOfarrs.length; z++) {
          System.out.print (Arrays.toString (arrOfarrs[z]) + " ");
        a[z] = arrOfarrs[z][z];
        }

        System.out.println ();

   }
 }
```

Comment: `b` and `c` are arrays of the same size as `a` that contain zeros.  What did you expect?  `d` is an array with one element; that element is an array of five zeros.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  The only problem is the brackets in the output.  I used the Arrays.toString.  Would there be a way to remove the brackets some how?

Comment: OUTPUT:  [1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [10, 11, 12] [13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

Comment: I also put the new code above.

Comment: @harold
Well, the reason why I put an array inside another array is the following. My actual program does a lot of calculation. One array re-calculates and stores new numbers. There are several arrays doing the same. At the end, I need all the arrays to be stored into one array. If I want to output all the numbers at the end, I would be needing that one main array. (Instead of several arrays being outputted one after another.) All numbers must be sorted at the end in the main array..

Answer (score 0):

There are two different operations with arrays in Java:

- initialization an array - when you create a new array with given size and default values (e.g. for `int` the default value is `0`, for `Object` - `null`)

```java
int[] arr = new int[5];  // i.e. arr = {0,0,0,0,0}
```

- write data into an array - when you put required date into created array

```java
arr[0] = 2; arr[1] = 7; arr[2] = 32;
arr[3] = 8; arr[4] = 2;
```

Moreover, you can do both operations at the same time:

```java
int[] arr = {2,7,32,8,2};
```

E.g. from your snippet:

```java
int[] a = { 2, 7, 32, 8, 2 }; // create a new array with given values
int[] b = new int[a.length];  // create a new array with size 5 (a.length = 5) => b = {0,0,0,0,0};
int[] c = new int[b.length];  // create a new array with size 5 (b.length = 5) => c = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

And it's obvious this snippet will print content of an array `b` which is `{0,0,0,0,0}`

```java
for (int id = 0; id < b.length; id++) {
    System.out.print(b[id] + " ");
}
```

And this one will print content of an array `c` which is `{0,0,0,0,0}`

```java
for (int y = 0; y < c.length; y++) {
    System.out.print(c.length + " ");
}
```

About 2D array. In java this is nothing more than **array of arrays**. Each row is an array.

So when you init an array like this:

```java
int[][] d = { b };
```

it means, that you define a 2D array with 1 row and this 1 row contain array `b`. By the way, each row in 2D array can have different length. I.e. in other way:

```java
int[][] d = new int[1][];  // first [] is amount of rows, second - columns
d[0] = b;
```

To print 2D array you have to go through all rows (the first loop), and then all columns (the second loop).

```java
for (int row = 0; row < d.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < d[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(d[row][col].length + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the nested (row, col)  is giving me an error. Unless I am missing something. It says,  "error: int cannot be dereferenced" System.out.print(d[row][col].length + " ");  I will check it again.